# Doing basic linear algebra in Spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-algebra

Does Spark 2.4 have Vector and Matrix classes that support basic linear algebra operations like dot product, norm, matrix and vector multiplication?  I can't find any linear algebra support in classes like Vector, DenseVector, or RowMatrix.

Older versions of Spark had org.jblas.DoubleMatrix, but that doesn't exist in Spark 2.4 and I can't find what they replaced it with.

Where do I look for linear algebra examples in spark 2.4?

I don't need RDDs for my current need (cosine similarity).

Comment: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: You can also consider using dn4j or dn4s.

Answer (score 3):

I've [found](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4699) that JBlas was removed due to incompatible license and replaced with [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java). You might want to look into it, this is a wrapper for low-level BLAS, LAPACK and ARPACK.

MLLib has the capabilities for Dense and Sparse Vectors/Matrices, they are based on RDDs: (I understand that you are looking for the low-level implementation)

For Vectors and Matrices you can use: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, Matrix, Matrices} these have support for dense and sparse vectors and matrices.

RowMatrix will be: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

You can refer to the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html

In fact, you can find the cosine similarity implementation in the MLlib repo: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/CosineSimilarity.scala

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Daniel Sobrado good response, spark 2.4 also comes with Breeze support [Breeze Linear Algebra](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Breeze-Linear-Algebra)
This library has the benefits that matrices default to column major ordering, like Matlab, but indexing is 0-based, like Numpy. 
Breeze supports indexing and slicing, linear algebra functions 
`(Linear solve, transpose, Determinant, Inverse, Eigenvalues , Eigenvectors, Singular Value Decomposition)` and operations `(Vector dot product, Elementwise addition, Shaped/Matrix multiplication, Elementwise multiplication, Elementwise max, Elementwise argmax), etc.`
Its to be noted that Breeze uses netlib-java for its core linear algebra routines
Below is an example of scala code that uses Breeze

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseVector
import com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object Breeze1 {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Init logging...")
    System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_KEY, "TRACE");
    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("main")
    log.trace("Starting...")
    val b = BLAS.getInstance()
    log.trace(s"BLAS = $b")
    val v = DenseVector(1,2,3,4)
    log.trace("Ending.")
  }
}
```